# Bulk/Batch update using PostgreSQL java

Tags: java, jooq, postgresql-10

I am doing insertion/Updation into table using below command .

```
insertResult = ((InsertReturningStep) ctx.insertInto(jOOQEntity, insertFields)          
        .values(insertValue).onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
        .set(tableFieldMapping.duplicateInsertMap)).returning().fetch();
```

But using above command I am able to insert/update one record at a time.
I want to update multiple record at a single command.

For this i am sending List of values for same fields into value but i am getting below error .

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of values must match the number of fields"

Is there any solution to update bulk records at a one shot